# Make a radio button input from a form public in C#?

Tags: c#, forms, enums, radio-button, public

I've got code and i know I'm 99% of the way there.  C# coding in MS VS2008.

Basically I have a form that has 4 radio buttons and a Continue button.  the user clicks one of the radio buttons and clicks continue, and this all works fine.

However, I want to use the value entered by the user (i.e. if they click the first button, I want a variable equal to 1, 2nd button equals 2 and so on).  I tried doing this in various points but the only place I can get it to run is in the private void btnOkClick line, which means I can use the values outside this void, which is what I really want.

I've tried playing around with setting some enums and such (commented out in the code below), but I can't quite get it.  I know I must be close but my novice-ness is truly showing as I keep reading posts and can't quite grasp it.

In short, I want to be able to have other classes in my VS2008 project be able to reference whatever value the user selected in the initial form.

```
namespace AmortClient
{
    public partial class frmLoadACTFCST : Form
    {
        public frmLoadACTFCST()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //set the parent of the form to the container
            //this.MdiParent = parent;
        }

        //public enum ACTFCST
        //{
        //    ACT = 1,
        //    FCST = 2,
        //    PLAN = 3,
        //    FiveYearPlan2012=4
        //}

        //private ACTFCST _actfcst = ACTFCST.ACT;
        //public ACTFCST actfcst
        //{
        //    get { return _actfcst; }
        //    set { _actfcst = value; }
        //}

        private void frmLoadACTFCST_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            

        }

        private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnActual_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnForecast_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnPlan_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btn5YrPlan2012_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }    

        private void btnContinue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string ACTFCSTtext = "";
            int dataTypeKey = 0;

            if (btnActual.Checked)
            {
                ACTFCSTtext = btnActual.Text;
                dataTypeKey = 1;
            }
            else if (btnForecast.Checked)
            {
                ACTFCSTtext = btnForecast.Text;
                dataTypeKey = 2;
            }

            else if (btnPlan.Checked)
            {
                ACTFCSTtext = btnPlan.Text;
                dataTypeKey = 3;
            }

            else if (btn5YrPlan2012.Checked)
            {
                ACTFCSTtext = btn5YrPlan2012.Text;
                dataTypeKey = 4;
            }

            string msg = "";
            msg = ACTFCSTtext + " " + dataTypeKey;

            //btn5YrPlan2012
            MessageBox.Show(msg);
            Close();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: if i understand your question you need to access controls on one form from another? you can change any control modifier to "public" which will allow you to access it outside that form.

Comment: He's declaring them within his btnContinue_Click method, which means they only have the scope of that method (i.e. they are garbage collected after that method finishes).  They should be instance variables, if I'm understanding his needs.

Comment: Nope, jsut want to be able to pass the variable to another class.  Seems like everyone wants to pass variables from 1 form to another.  mine is easier.  Essentially, the value of 1 (if choosing the first radio button), will be passed through and SQL query I run in a later class.

Comment: Jim, you're right, they are in a void so they get dumped and that isn't what I want.  As you stated, i want the variables avaliable publicly.  I've got a 900 page c# book in front of me with no referenc eto instance variables, are they called something else?

Comment: Instance variable is the same thing as a Class variable, or member - it's a variable that is owned by a class and is in scope for the duration of that class's lifecycle.  You should really read up on variable scopes.  http://www.codecandle.com/Articles/191/Csharp/Variables/Variable-scope/codedetail.aspx

Comment: ironically, I understand the concept of variable scope in msot cases, it's the coding I don't get.  I use class variables and local variables quite a bit so those are pretty easy.   I know what the void does and why it doesn't work.  But it's the only place i could put my statements that actually at least returned the values I wanted, even if the void kills them before I can use them.  I'm most surprised that the examples of the coding of pulling data from a form and using in another class NOT through a form seems rare. The list of stuff i need to learn is longer than Santa Claus' list lol :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dataTypeKey and ACTFCSTtext variables need to be declared as instance variables for your Form object if you want to access them from any other methods within your form.  If you want to use them with some other form, you can pass them either as constructor arguments, or set some properties of said other form.

So you'd declare them just after the class declaration if you want them to be instance variables.  They should still be private, meaning they can only be accessed from within your frmLoadACTFCST class.

```
public partial class frmLoadACTFCST : Form
{
    private string ACTFCSTtext = "";
    private int dataTypeKey = 0;
...
```

EDIT: if you want to access variables from one object in a different object (or static class), your options are as follows...

1) Declare your variables as public instance variables (same as shown above but public; these are known as Properties when you give them getter and setter methods).  Your class that needs access to these variables would need to have a reference to the class that owns the variables.

Example:
FormA has a public property named SomeString.
FormB needs to access SomeString. 
FormB needs a reference to FormA, and would access the variable as...

```
formAReference.SomeString
```

2) Pass the values of the variables as arguments to some method for the class that needs access.

Example:
FormA has a private instance variable named SomeString.
FormB needs access to SomeString.
If FormA instantiates FormB, it can pass the value of SomeString to FormB's constructor...

```
//From within FormA's code
FormB formB = new FormB(SomeString);

//FormB's constructor
public FormB(string someString)
{
    this.someString = someString;
}
```

Comment: Is that the only change?  When I try to do something simple like MessageBox.Show(ACTFCSTtext); in another class it says "the name ACTFCSTText does not exist in the current context".

Comment: Your question wasn't really clear on where you want to use the variables.  A private instance variable can be used anywhere within the same class it was declared in.  If you want to use it in some other class, your options are to make it public (not necessarily best practice, but not necessarily bad practice either depending on your needs), in which case you'd need to have a reference to the owning object to access its public members, or else you can pass the values to your target class as method arguments; perhaps even in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I keep seeing these examples passing data from one form to another and wish that was what I needed.  I think I need a weekend away from code.  I can't even get frmLoacACTFCST.ACTFCSTText to show up in a MessageBox lol.  Makes no sense that i can;t figure this out, the form solution has to be harder than just simply using a variable like ActFcstText.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a smarter way to do it.

```
public partial class frmLoadACTFCST : Form
{
    public frmLoadACTFCST()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        actfcst = ACTFCST.ACT;
        btnActual.Tag = ACTFCST.ACT;
        btnActual.Checked = true;
        btnForecast.Tag = ACTFCST.FCST; 
        btnPlan.Tag = ACTFSCT.PLAN;
        btn5YrPlan2012.Tag = ACTFCST.FiveYearPlan2012;
    }

    public enum ACTFCST
    {
        ACT = 1,
        FCST = 2,
        PLAN = 3,
        FiveYearPlan2012=4
    }

    public static ACTFCST actfcst { get; private set; }

    private void CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // All the buttons uses this Click-event.
        actfcst = (sender as Button).Tag as ACTFCST;
    }

    private void btnContinue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(actfcst.ToString());
        Close();
    }
}
```

The point is that all the buttons calls CheckedChanged when clicked.

Using a static means that others can access the value using something like this:

```
frmLoadACTFCST.ACTFCST value = frmLoadACTFCST.actfcst;
// Do something based on value.
```

I hope this helps you in yoyr quest.

Answer (score 0):

If you select a control in design view, the properties window contains an item named "Modifiers".  You can make the control public here.

A better way would be to create a new public property on your form that yields the value of the currently selected radio button.